# EulerMatrix with axes other than X, Y an Z

Tags: matrix, coordinate-transformation, rotation, geometric-transform

The Mathematica function `EulerMatrix[{Alpha, Beta, Gamma},{a,b,c}]` gives the Euler matrix for rotation about X, Y and Z axes. Here by choosing the order of a, b and c, we can change the order of rotations with respect to the three axes.

My question is, how to find Euler matrix for a rotation for which the "old" axes are not X, Y and Z axes. For example, I want to find a Euler Matrix in {3, 1, 3} format for which Old axes are, Axis 1 = {1, -1, 0}, Axis 2 = {1, 1, -2} and Axis 3 = {1, 1, 1}.

Will appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

You could use `RotationMatrix` to build your own EulerMatrix by rotating about your custom axes 1,2, and 3.

First check that you can reproduce `EulerMatrix[{\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma]}, {3, 1, 3}]` with `RotationMatrix`:

```
RotationMatrix[\[Alpha], {0, 0, 1}].RotationMatrix[\[Beta], {1, 0,0}].RotationMatrix[\[Gamma], {0, 0, 1}]
(* Check this is equivalent to EulerMatrix[{\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma]}, {3, 1, 3}] *)
EulerMatrix[{\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma]}, {3, 1, 3}] - % // Simplify 
(* {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}} *)
```

Now rotate about your custom axes 1,2,3 in the format 3-1-3:

```
(* Define custom axis *)
Axis1 = {1, -1, 0}; Axis2 = {1, 1, -2}; Axis3 = {1, 1, 1};
(* Euler Matrix in 3-1-3 format about the custom axis*)
RotationMatrix[\[Alpha], Axis3].RotationMatrix[\[Beta],Axis1].RotationMatrix[\[Gamma], Axis3]//Simplify
```

Comment: Thanks. First one works fine. But, is the second one in {1, 2, 3} format rather than {3, 1, 3} ?? In {3, 1, 3} format, should it be RotationMatrix[\[Gamma], {1, 1, 1}].RotationMatrix[\[Beta], {1,-1,0}].RotationMatrix[\[Alpha], {1, 1, 1}] ?

Comment: @user49535 See answer after editing

Answer (score 2):

It is simpler to work with normalized axes.
If you have old axes given by: old={{1,0,0},{0,1,0},0,0,1}} and you want Euler rotation around new axes: new, you may rotate a vector vec relative to the new system by first transforming the vector to the new system, apply the Euler rotation and transform the vector back to the old system.

Toward this aim, we define a rotation matrix (axis rotation matrix): arm that rotates the old axes into new axes. Note that the columns of this matrix are the new axis in the old system. Further,this matrix transforms coordinates from the old system into coordinates in the new system.
We define a second rotation matrix (vector rotation matrix): vrm, that rotates a vector vec={1,1,1}/Sqrt[3] in the new system.
Here is the code and graphics for this:

```
old = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
orig = {0, 0, 0};
vec = {1, 1, 1}/Sqrt[3];
Row[{Red, "Vector   ", Green, "New Axes   ", Black, "Old Axes"}]
Manipulate[
 arm = EulerMatrix[{a, b, c}];
 vrm = EulerMatrix[{va, vb, vc}];
 rotvec = Inverse[arm].vrm.arm.vec;(*here is the vector rotated*)
 Graphics3D[{
   Arrow[{orig, #}] & /@ old
   , Green, Arrow[{orig, #}] & /@ Transpose@arm, 
   MapThread[Text[#2, 1.1 #1] &, {Transpose@arm, {"xn", "yn", "zn"}}]
   , Red, Arrow[{orig, #}] &[rotvec]
   }, SphericalRegion -> True, Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
 , {{va, 0, "a-vec"}, 0, 2 Pi}, {{vb, 0, "b-vec"}, 0, 
  Pi}, {{vc, 0, "c-vec"}, 0, 2 Pi}, {{a, 0, "a-axes"}, 0, 
  2 Pi}, {{b, 0, "b-axes"}, 0, Pi}, {{c, 0, "c-axes"}, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]